# Head First: servlets and JSP - can I use newer version of Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I know that this question may be silly or far away from the Stackoverflow standards, but I need to know one thing:

Can I use a newer version of Tomcat while working with the book `Head First: Servlets and JSP`? In the book Tomcat in version 5 is used, I want to use Tomcat 8.

Are there differences between Tomcat 5 and 8 that will make my work impossible?

Comment: Sure, you can. But if you're learning with such an old book, you'll be missing many features that didn't exist back then (like annotations for example).

Comment: @JBNizet - and is there anything newer source of knowledge to learn servlets and jsp?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I started learning them in 1999, so from there, I just read blogs, articles, the specification, etc.

Comment: To add on to @JBNizet comment,using newer version or Tomcat will provide additional features in addition to supporting older features as well(being backward compatible).This is used to ensure there are no breaking changes which could lead to application breakdown,